# Trying to write code using emu8086 to get Surface Area and I keep coming across this error. (64) not enough operands for ADD

Tags: assembly, emu8086

Here is the code in question for getting Surface Area of A rectangle using 8086
I'm open to any suggestions and corrections as well.

```
INCLUDE 'EMU8086.INC'
DATA SEGMENT
Length    DB ?
Height    DB ?
Width     DB ?
RES  DB 10 DUP ('$')
MSG1 DB "ENTER Length : $"
MSG3 DB "ENTER Height : $"
MSG4 DB "ENTER Width  : $"
MSG2 DB 10,13,"Surface Area : $"

DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME DS:DATA,CS:CODE

START:
    MOV AX,DATA
    MOV DS,AX
    
    LEA DX,MSG1
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH,1
    INT 21H
    SUB AL,30H
    MOV Length,AL
    MOV AH,0
 ;===========================================================   
    PRINTN
    LEA DX,MSG3
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH,1
    INT 21H
    SUB AL,30H
    MOV Height,AL
    MOV AH,0 
;===============================================================    
    PRINTN
    LEA DX,MSG4
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H
    
    MOV AH,1
    INT 21H
    SUB AL,30H
    MOV Width,AL
    MOV AH,0
;===================================================================    
    MOV AL, Length
    MOV DL, Height
    MUL DL
    
    MOV RES, AL 
    
    MOV DL, Width 
    MOV AL, Height
    MUL DL
    
    ADD RES
    MOV RES, AL 
     
    MOV AL, Length
    MOV DL, Width
    MUL DL 
    
    ADD RES
    
    MOV BL, 2
    MUL BL
    
;==================================================================    
    LEA SI,RES
    CALL HEX2DEC
    LEA DX,MSG2
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H
    LEA DX,RES
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H
    
MOV AH,4CH
INT 21H
CODE ENDS

    HEX2DEC PROC NEAR
        
    MOV CX,0
    MOV BX,10
    
   LOOP1: MOV DX,0
    DIV BX
    ADD DL,30H
    PUSH DX
    INC CX
    CMP AX,9
    JG LOOP1
    ADD AL,30H
    MOV [SI],AL
    
   LOOP2: POP AX
    INC SI
    MOV [SI],AL
    LOOP LOOP2
   RET
HEX2DEC ENDP
END START
```

Comment: Which part of the error message is unclear? `ADD` needs 2 operands. Did you consult an instruction set reference?

Comment: This is not a [mcve] of your question about how `add` works.  All that other code, including valid forms of the `add` instruction like `ADD DL,30H`, are just clutter, not relevant for asking something about a one-operand form of `add` that you guessed might exist.  Your question doesn't even say what things you want added together; Sep had to guess from context in his answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Although `mul` implicitly uses the accumulator register, the `add` instruction does not! For `add` you must specify both a destination and a source operand.

> ```
> ADD RES
> MOV RES, AL
> ```

could become

```
ADD AL, RES
MOV RES, AL
```

but it's better to write this in one instruction as

```
ADD RES, AL
```

---

> ```
> ADD RES
> MOV BL, 2
> MUL BL
> ```

Same error here, but this time we want the sum in `AX` anyway (for later output) so just add *RES* to `AL`. And because multiplying by 2 is much faster using a shift to the left, this snippet becomes

```
ADD AL, RES
SHL AX, 1
```

---

> ```
>  JG LOOP1
>  ADD AL,30H
>  MOV [SI],AL    <<< leading zero?
>
> LOOP2:
>  POP AX
>  INC SI
>  MOV [SI],AL
>  LOOP LOOP2
> ```

Is it intentional to prepend a 0 to the result? You can change pre-increment into post-increment and get rid of that ugly leading zero:

> ```
>  JG LOOP1
>
> LOOP2:
>  POP AX
>  MOV [SI],AL
>  INC SI
>  LOOP LOOP2
> ```